# Compare graphs by using different slopes

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions, self-learning, slope

I have two equations

First one is $\beta q_1 x_1 + q_2 x_2 =I-\gamma$

Second one is $q_1x_1+q_2 x_2=I$

where $\beta q_1\lt q_1$ and $I-\gamma\lt I$ and all are positive.

The slope of the first model is =-$q_2\over\beta q_1$

And the slope of the second model is =-$q_2\over q_1$

I think the first slope is greater than the second slope. Right? I am not sure. Please check the comparison again.

Then, how are their graphs? I posted below. First figure or second figure represents the equations ?

Which graph is true?

The second one seems more correct to me. Am I right?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second one is correct!

Because $I - \gamma < I$, you get $\frac{I - \gamma}{q_2} < \frac{I}{q_2} $

That enables you to find the intersections with the $x_2$ axis like you have in the second drawing.

On the other hand, the slopes you found are wrong! Or at least the ones yoi wrote in your question. Please review the steps you did. Can you find the mistake?

As you ask, I will do the second equation:

$$q_1 x_1 + q_2 x_2 = I \iff q_2 x_2 = -q_1x_1 + I \iff x_2 = -\frac{q_1}{q_2}x_1 + \frac{I}{q_2}$$

Comment: Well, how to draw correct graph? Can you post the correct one? Dear @rgs because I am confused like you. And I need to draw such a graph and I have these budget lines

Comment: Dear rgs, $q_2$/$\beta q_1$>$q_2/q_1$ . Right? But since they are negative slope, that is to say, we multiply with minus one, we get $-q_2$/$\beta q_1$<$-q_2/q_1$ so the second graph is correct again when we look at their slopes. Am I right?

Comment: Really? I cannot see my mistake in finding slopes. Where is the mistake in slopes?

Comment: Then First one slope is $\beta q_1\over q_2$ and the second slope is $q_1\over q_2$ ? Right now is it true?

Comment: Okay:) then the second is correct right now! I am sooo so happy to find this question thank you so much:)) dear rgs